# Validate request parameters in Azure APIM

Tags: azure-api-management

I define a `full-name` API that takes in First Name and Last Name and combine them to return the Full Name:

```
https://my-org.azure-api.net/my-app/full-name?firstName=John&lastName=Smith
# Returns: John Smith
```

In Azure APIM, I set both `firstName` and `lastName` parameters as "Required" in the API Schema.

In the Inbound policy, I want to validate that both are present in the request. I found the [validate-parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validation-policies#validate-parameters) policy which appears to do just that:

```xml
<inbound>
    <validate-parameters specified-parameter-action="prevent"
                         unspecified-parameter-action="detect"
                         errors-variable-name="validationErrors" />
</inbound>
```

To my surprise, this does absolution nothing! I have to run a manual check on each param (this code is so verbose):

```xml
<inbound>
    <choose>
        <when condition="@( context.Request.OriginalUrl.Query.GetValueOrDefault("firstName") == null )">
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
                <set-header name="Context-Type" exists-action="override">
                    <value>text/plain</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-body>'firstName' is required</set-body>
            </return-response>
        </when>
        <when condition="@( context.Request.OriginalUrl.Query.GetValueOrDefault("lastName") == null )">
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
                <set-header name="Context-Type" exists-action="override">
                    <value>text/plain</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-body>'lastName' is required</set-body>
            </return-response>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</inbound>
```

Is there any more convenient way to validate the request against the API's schema in Azure APIM?

Comment: same behavior - validation does not fire - even when creating API with api-version=2021-01-01-preview - I will ask the product group

Answer (score 0):

We can find the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validation-policies#validate-parameters) shows us we need to use api-version which later than `2021-01-01-preview` to create the api in APIM, then the policy can work.

[image]

So if your api in APIM was created in past, you need to create it again. I checked the create api operation on azure portal, it has been updated to using `api-version=2021-01-01-preview` shown as below screenshot.

[image]

You can also request the [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2021-01-01-preview/apis/createorupdate) to create it by yourself.

Comment: sorry, as I already wrote above - this is exactly what I did and it did not work - there has to be another problem

Comment: May I ask what RuntimeVersion the endpoint /internal-status-0123456789abcdef is reporting for you? I get "RuntimeVersion":"0.19.1197.0",...,"LastUpgradeStartTime":"05 May 2021 12:05"

Comment: I checked my version and it said "2021-01-01-preview". The `validate-parameters` policy seems to do nothing for me at the moment

Answer (score 0):

you seems to have missed specifying child node "query" nodes as in the documentation.

```html
<inbound>
    <validate-parameters specified-parameter-action="prevent" unspecified-parameter-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="requestParametersValidation"> 
    <query specified-parameter-action="prevent" unspecified-parameter-action="prevent">
        <parameter name="firstName" action="prevent" />
        <parameter name="lastName" action="prevent" />        
    </query>   
</validate-parameters>
</inbound>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-parameters-policy